# What tool is used by VS to pack .xap files?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I mean, what it calls internally to pack them as zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you even care? But if you are looking for a zip library that you can use yourself, take a look at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). I have used it myself to extract a .config file from a .xap archive, edit it, and add it back to the xap archive. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I just don't want to pull in any additional references.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the tool i thinks its a *MSBUILD* task "XapPackager" defined in Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.dll ,

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.XapPackager"  AssemblyFile="Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone.Build.Tasks.dll" />
```

You can get more information from reading 'Microsoft.Silverlight.targets' file

http://ngenerics.googlecode.com/svn-history/r318/trunk/Source/Dependencies/SilverlightForPhoneV4.0/Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets